# Choosing one task out of two in oTree

Tags: javascript, python, otree

I have 2 tasks in oTree, both of them consist of radio buttons.
Both of the tasks needs to be in the same page, but when the participant will choose to answer one of the forms, I want to disable the other form.
In other words, there is 2 forms but the participants should answer only one of the forms.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: To clarify: Do you want the player to only complete one of the tasks (and not let them proceed if they complete both) or do you need to hide one task once the other has been completed? Can you please post the code of both the `Page` class as well as the HTML template?